# Find a function that is orthonormal to both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$?

Tags: integration, functions, vectors, hilbert-spaces

Find a function of the form $\ f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ that is orthonormal to both $\ g(x) = 1$ and $\ h(x) = 1+x$ in $\ L_2(-1,1)$?

Comment: Write the orthogonality condition, solve for coefficients.

Comment: Hi. In order to get some responses, you should show what you have tried. Let others know what you have difficulties with. Otherwise you might get downvoted or have your question closed.

Comment: You could also perform the Gram-Schmidt procedure on $1, 1 + x, x^2$. The last vector in the resulting list will be orthogonal to $1$ and $1 + x$, while still belonging to the span of $1, 1+x, x^2$, which will still be in the form $ax^2 + bx + c$.

Comment: At least try something.

Comment: @Andrei I tried assuming arbitrary coefficients and applying the orthogonality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions for orthogonality
$$\int_{-1}^1\,f(x)g(x)\,dx=0;\;\int_{-1}^1\,f(x)h(x)\,dx=0$$
Condition for normality
$$\int_{-1}^1\,f^2(x)\,dx=1$$

$$\int_{-1}^1\,(ax^2+bx+c)\,dx=\left[\frac{ax^3}{3}+\frac{bx^2}{2}+cx\right]_{-1}^1=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c-\left(-\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}-c\right)=\frac{2a}{3}+2c$$

$$\int_{-1}^1\,(ax^2+bx+c)(x+1)\,dx= \frac{2}{3} (a + b + 3 c)$$

$$\int_{-1}^1\,(ax^2+bx+c)^2\,dx= \frac{2a^2}{5}+ \frac{4 a c}{3} + \frac{2 b^2}{3} + 2 c^2$$

We get the system

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{2a}{3}+2c=0\\
\frac{2}{3} (a + b + 3 c)=0\\
\frac{2a^2}{5}+ \frac{4 a c}{3} + \frac{2 b^2}{3} + 2 c^2=1
\end{array}
\right.
$

simplified

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a+3c=0\\
a + b + 3 c=0\\
6a^2+20ac+10b^2+30c^2=15
\end{array}
\right.
$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a=-3c\\
b=0\\
6a^2+20ac+30c^2=15
\end{array}
\right.
$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a=-3c\\
b=0\\
54c^2-60c^2+30c^2=15\to 24c^2=15 \to c^2=\frac{5}{8}
\end{array}
\right.
$

two solutions
$\left(-3\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}},0,\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}\right);\;\left(3\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}},0,-\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}\right)$

Hope this helps